# Python - Keras - Is this identical image preprocessing?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I have the question if I manually process the image in the same way that the train generator does. I am using python3 and keras.

This is how the training data is processed.

```
train_datagen = keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255,
    #shear_range=0.2,
    #zoom_range=0.2,
    #horizontal_flip=True,
)
test_datagen = keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    str(Files.join(self.directory, 'training')),
    target_size=(self.width, self.height),
    color_mode="rgb",
    batch_size=self.batch_size,
    class_mode=class_mode,
    shuffle=True,
    seed=42
)
validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    str(Files.join(self.directory, 'validation')),
    target_size=(self.width, self.height),
    color_mode="rgb",
    batch_size=self.batch_size,
    class_mode=class_mode,
    shuffle=False,
    seed=42,
)
self.model.fit(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=train_samples_count // self.batch_size,
    epochs=self.epochs,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    validation_steps=validation_samples_count // self.batch_size,
    callbacks=callbacks,
)
```

And this is how a single image is processed.

```
img = keras.preprocessing.image.load_img(path, target_size=(self.width, self.height), color_mode='rgb')
img_tensor = keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(img)
img_tensor = np.expand_dims(img_tensor, axis=0)channels)
img_tensor /= 255.
self.model.predict(img_tensor)
```

Is this processed in the same way?

Comment: If you are using same functionality to preprocess the image in both the case it will be almost the same result except small threshold difference while calculating.