# Huge difference in keras validation precision and manual evaluation precision. (Python3 Keras)

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

There seems to be a huge precision difference in the keras model.evaluate and in my manual evaluation. Which i can't explain.

These are the training and keras evaluation logs.

```
Training:
 * dataset: /etc/crypto/dataset/exchange_alpaca_symbols_250-seq_length_4-width_128-height_128-scale_2.5-ratio_0.33_0.33_0.33/
 * train samples: 37797
 * validation samples: 9450
Found 37797 images belonging to 3 classes.
 * class_indices: {'bearish_1': 0, 'bullish_1': 1, 'normal': 2}
Found 9450 images belonging to 3 classes.
2021-08-11 22:14:19.374432: I tensorflow/compiler/mlir/mlir_graph_optimization_pass.cc:176] None of the MLIR Optimization Passes are enabled (registered 2)
2021-08-11 22:14:19.393402: I tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:114] CPU Frequency: 3999980000 Hz
Epoch 1/50
590/590 [==============================] - 1040s 2s/step - loss: 0.9058 - accuracy: 0.5142 - precision: 0.6863 - recall: 0.2499 - val_loss: 0.8197 - val_accuracy: 0.5663 - val_precision: 0.8139 - val_recall: 0.2454
Epoch 2/50
590/590 [==============================] - 1036s 2s/step - loss: 0.8245 - accuracy: 0.5619 - precision: 0.6964 - recall: 0.3257 - val_loss: 0.8118 - val_accuracy: 0.5654 - val_precision: 0.6212 - val_recall: 0.4641
Epoch 3/50
590/590 [==============================] - 1036s 2s/step - loss: 0.8114 - accuracy: 0.5746 - precision: 0.6957 - recall: 0.3554 - val_loss: 0.7968 - val_accuracy: 0.5804 - val_precision: 0.7403 - val_recall: 0.3260
Epoch 4/50
590/590 [==============================] - 1035s 2s/step - loss: 0.8010 - accuracy: 0.5798 - precision: 0.6948 - recall: 0.3704 - val_loss: 0.7930 - val_accuracy: 0.5828 - val_precision: 0.6785 - val_recall: 0.4072
Epoch 5/50
590/590 [==============================] - 1035s 2s/step - loss: 0.7922 - accuracy: 0.5858 - precision: 0.6960 - recall: 0.3880 - val_loss: 0.7958 - val_accuracy: 0.5824 - val_precision: 0.6376 - val_recall: 0.4689
Epoch 6/50
590/590 [==============================] - 1035s 2s/step - loss: 0.7851 - accuracy: 0.5961 - precision: 0.6919 - recall: 0.4051 - val_loss: 0.7850 - val_accuracy: 0.5914 - val_precision: 0.7227 - val_recall: 0.3543
Epoch 7/50
590/590 [==============================] - 1036s 2s/step - loss: 0.7786 - accuracy: 0.6022 - precision: 0.6922 - recall: 0.4277 - val_loss: 0.7821 - val_accuracy: 0.5867 - val_precision: 0.6624 - val_recall: 0.4311
Epoch 8/50
590/590 [==============================] - 1035s 2s/step - loss: 0.7696 - accuracy: 0.6108 - precision: 0.6939 - recall: 0.4522 - val_loss: 0.7833 - val_accuracy: 0.5968 - val_precision: 0.6905 - val_recall: 0.4226
Epoch 9/50
590/590 [==============================] - 1035s 2s/step - loss: 0.7602 - accuracy: 0.6156 - precision: 0.6950 - recall: 0.4658 - val_loss: 0.7878 - val_accuracy: 0.5897 - val_precision: 0.6951 - val_recall: 0.3885
Epoch 10/50
590/590 [==============================] - 1035s 2s/step - loss: 0.7538 - accuracy: 0.6270 - precision: 0.6962 - recall: 0.4902 - val_loss: 0.7896 - val_accuracy: 0.5997 - val_precision: 0.6665 - val_recall: 0.4549
Epoch 11/50
590/590 [==============================] - 1035s 2s/step - loss: 0.7440 - accuracy: 0.6294 - precision: 0.6948 - recall: 0.5093 - val_loss: 0.7810 - val_accuracy: 0.6007 - val_precision: 0.6604 - val_recall: 0.4655
Epoch 12/50
590/590 [==============================] - 1035s 2s/step - loss: 0.7373 - accuracy: 0.6372 - precision: 0.7013 - recall: 0.5250 - val_loss: 0.7921 - val_accuracy: 0.5931 - val_precision: 0.6419 - val_recall: 0.4968
Epoch 13/50
590/590 [==============================] - 1035s 2s/step - loss: 0.7268 - accuracy: 0.6464 - precision: 0.7018 - recall: 0.5436 - val_loss: 0.8048 - val_accuracy: 0.5979 - val_precision: 0.6531 - val_recall: 0.4844
Epoch 14/50
590/590 [==============================] - 1035s 2s/step - loss: 0.7169 - accuracy: 0.6541 - precision: 0.7044 - recall: 0.5647 - val_loss: 0.8292 - val_accuracy: 0.5998 - val_precision: 0.6489 - val_recall: 0.5046
Epoch 15/50
590/590 [==============================] - 1035s 2s/step - loss: 0.7064 - accuracy: 0.6629 - precision: 0.7102 - recall: 0.5764 - val_loss: 0.7980 - val_accuracy: 0.5992 - val_precision: 0.6450 - val_recall: 0.5199
Epoch 16/50
590/590 [==============================] - 1035s 2s/step - loss: 0.6981 - accuracy: 0.6717 - precision: 0.7155 - recall: 0.5966 - val_loss: 0.8167 - val_accuracy: 0.5951 - val_precision: 0.6297 - val_recall: 0.5237
12-08-21 02:50:28 - Saving model weights to /vserver/storages/crypto/crypto/.cache/weights/neuralnet.1.1.21.h5 ... done
Training evaluation: loss: 0.713 - accuracy: 0.65 - precision: 0.728 - recall: 0.51
Validation evaluation: loss: 0.78 - accuracy: 0.602 - precision: 0.662 - recall: 0.467
```

And this is my manual evaluation.

```
Evaluation:
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
version: 1.1.21
database: /etc/crypto/dataset/evaluation-alpaca-period_01-06-2021_01-07-2021_symbols_custom_1000/evaluation/
from: 01-06-21 16:00:00
till: 30-06-21 21:00:00
total days: 29.2
max profits bullish_1:  514.61%
max profits bearish_1:  406.51%
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Confusion matrix:
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                av_lost_profits av_profits  av_win_profits  earned    lost  precision profits  recall  usdt_profits  win_ratio
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
normal 25%:                0.00        0.0            0.00     0.0     0.0       1.00    0.0%    0.86      10000.00       0.00
bullish_1 25%:            -0.90      0.04%            0.94  3184.0  3209.0       0.03   4.56%    0.31      10448.88       0.50
bearish_1 25%:            -0.97     -0.04%            0.87  5675.0  6060.0       0.03  -5.09%    0.57       9488.04       0.48
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
normal 35%:                0.00        0.0            0.00     0.0     0.0       1.00    0.0%    0.87      10000.00       0.00
bullish_1 35%:            -0.90      0.04%            0.95  3139.0  3174.0       0.03    4.7%    0.31      10463.58       0.50
bearish_1 35%:            -0.98     -0.04%            0.88  5636.0  6019.0       0.03  -5.18%    0.57       9479.89       0.48
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
normal 40%:                0.00        0.0            0.00     0.0     0.0       1.00    0.0%    0.88      10000.00       0.00
bullish_1 40%:            -0.95      0.05%            1.00  2625.0  2644.0       0.04   6.03%    0.29      10601.21       0.50
bearish_1 40%:            -1.01     -0.04%            0.92  5018.0  5355.0       0.03   -5.1%    0.56       9485.81       0.48
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
normal 50%:                0.00        0.0            0.00     0.0     0.0       1.00    0.0%    0.95      10000.00       0.00
bullish_1 50%:            -1.23       0.1%            1.26   877.0   871.0       0.07   12.1%    0.16      11227.78       0.50
bearish_1 50%:            -1.23     -0.06%            1.09  2260.0  2422.0       0.05  -8.13%    0.39       9190.03       0.48
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
normal 55%:                0.00        0.0            0.00     0.0     0.0       0.99    0.0%    0.98      10000.00       0.00
bullish_1 55%:            -1.27      0.08%            1.31   400.0   398.0       0.07   9.83%    0.08      10948.53       0.50
bearish_1 55%:            -1.26     -0.05%            1.09   998.0  1044.0       0.05  -6.16%    0.17       9360.44       0.49
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
normal 60%:                0.00        0.0            0.00     0.0    0.0       0.99     0.0%    0.99      10000.00       0.00
bullish_1 60%:            -1.38      0.06%            1.48   171.0  178.0       0.09    5.81%    0.04      10508.35       0.49
bearish_1 60%:            -1.26      -0.2%            1.10   286.0  355.0       0.04  -24.79%    0.05       7692.55       0.45
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
normal 65%:                0.00        0.0            0.00     0.0   0.0       0.99    0.0%    1.00      10000.00       0.00
bullish_1 65%:            -1.47      0.21%            1.67    74.0  70.0       0.12  13.88%    0.03      11321.62       0.51
bearish_1 65%:            -1.37     -0.02%            1.17    80.0  80.0       0.06  -1.21%    0.02       9618.41       0.50
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
normal 70%:                0.00        0.0            0.00     0.0   0.0       0.99    0.0%    1.00      10000.00       0.00
bullish_1 70%:            -1.37       0.0%            1.73    30.0  36.0       0.11   0.09%    0.01       9930.77       0.45
bearish_1 70%:            -1.72      0.33%            1.76    25.0  16.0       0.12  11.69%    0.01      10982.67       0.61
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
normal 75%:                0.00        0.0            0.00     0.0   0.0       0.99    0.0%    1.00      10000.00       0.00
bullish_1 75%:            -1.08      0.48%            2.10    12.0  13.0       0.16   10.1%    0.01      11008.72       0.48
bearish_1 75%:            -0.60      0.99%            2.58     5.0   5.0       0.10   9.91%    0.00      10995.70       0.50
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
normal 85%:                0.00        0.0            0.00     0.0   0.0       0.99    0.0%     1.0      10000.00       0.00
bullish_1 85%:            -0.62     -0.14%            0.84     1.0   2.0       0.00  -0.41%     0.0       9958.04       0.33
bearish_1 85%:             0.00          0            0.00     0.0   0.0       0.00    0.0%     0.0      10000.00       0.00
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
normal 95%:                 0.0         0.0             0.0     0.0   0.0       0.99    0.0%     1.0       10000.0        0.0
bullish_1 95%:              0.0         0.0             0.0     0.0   0.0       0.00    0.0%     0.0       10000.0        0.0
bearish_1 95%:              0.0         0.0             0.0     0.0   0.0       0.00    0.0%     0.0       10000.0        0.0
```

Yet the image's are processed in the same way (for the code view my other question about image processing [Python - Keras - Is this identical image preprocessing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68578871/python-keras-is-this-identical-image-preprocessing))

Precision formula.

```
precision = true_positives / (true_positives + false_positives)
```

Does anyone have an idea what could cause this?

Comment: how are you computing the precision ?

Comment: @Netim - precision = true_positives / (true_positives + false_positives)

Comment: I know, but can you give us you code for that ? because keras compute it like this `def precision(y_true, y_pred):
    y_true = K.ones_like(y_true) 
    true_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true * y_pred, 0, 1)))
    
    predicted_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_pred, 0, 1)))
    precision = true_positives / (predicted_positives + K.epsilon())
    return precision`

Comment: @Netim - Well the exact code is ```report["probability_range"][min_probability][class_]["precision"] = round(report["probability_range"][min_probability][class_]["true_positives"] / (report["probability_range"][min_probability][class_]["true_positives"] + report["probability_range"][min_probability][class_]["false_positives"]), 2)```. Yet the difference seems to be with 50% threshold manual evaluation 0.07 and the keras evaluation 0.662. Could this be caused by the differences in the keras precision function?

Comment: Okay my bad, I finally understand how to read your manual repport. You are heavily overfitting on class `normal`. Regarding you difference of precision this is due to the fact the keras is returning the average precision. Try using `print(classification_report(y_true, y_pred))` from `sklearn.metrics`. It will give  you a detail view of each metric for each class and in average